# How to literally read the word "MySQL"?

Tags: mysql

Is it "My Sequel" or "My S Q L"?

We need to have uniform pronunciation of this word in workspace. It's awkward if you keep saying  "My S Q L" all the time while your buddy says "My Sequel". And have this atmosphere of like waiting for who's gonna snap first and shout of what he thought is right lol.

Comment: *Potayto potahto tomayto tomahto*. Take your pick.

Comment: I just learned that MySql is developed by a Swede and "My" is the name of her daughter. And it's read as "Mee" (in swedish accent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the MySQL web site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/what-is-mysql.html#idm139761506951328):

> The official way to pronounce "MySQL" is "My Ess Que Ell" (not "my sequel"), but we do not mind if you pronounce it as "my sequel" or in some other localized way.

[This article](http://patorjk.com/blog/2012/01/26/pronouncing-sql-s-q-l-or-sequel/)  has more information on how to pronounce the generic term SQL, as opposed to the specific MySQL product.

Comment: aha! I knew it. I was baffled why would they name it sequel. sequel of what? lol